# Gitlab CI/CD variables: how to access environment scoped variables within jobs?

Tags: environment-variables, gitlab-ci

I have defined the following CI/CD variable (`VAULT_PATH`) in my gitlab project.

As you can see in the image, the variable is environment scoped so, in order to access its value within my jobs (`$VAULT_PATH`), I have added the environment property to each job.

```
job_build_preprod:
  environment: preprod
  script:
   - echo $VAULT_PATH

job_deploy_preprod:
  environment: preprod
  script:
   - echo $VAULT_PATH

job_build_production:
  environment: production
  script:
   - echo $VAULT_PATH

job_deploy_production:
  environment: production
  script:
   - echo $VAULT_PATH
```

The problem I am facing following this approach is that my "build" jobs are being tagged as deployment jobs (due to the fact that I am adding the environment property) when they are not.

But if I do not add the environment property, I cannot access the environment scoped variable that I need.

So, is there another way to access environment scoped variables within jobs without using the environment property?

I need to use them within build jobs, but I do not want gitlab to tag those build jobs as deployment jobs to the environment.

[image: img]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out `actions` inside environment https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#environmentaction.

There are a few actions which you can use which won't trigger deployment.

eg: for build u can use `prepare`

```
job_build_preprod
  script: 
    - echo $VAULT_PATH
  environment:
    name: preprod
    action: prepare
    url: https://test.com
```

Comment: Just what I need it! Thanks!!